# dbt python models and unitests

Tags: python, dbt

I have a dbt python model in my folder `foo`

```
 |-foo
 | |-post_to_api.py
 | |-test_post_to_api.py
 | |-foo.sql
```

How can I exclude all my python tests when I do `dbt run`?

```
dbt run --models foo --exclude foo.test_post_to_api
 
  Parsing Error in model test_post_to_api (models/geronimo/test_post_to_api.py)
  dbt allows exactly one model defined per python file, found 0
```

Or should I put my unittests in another location?

Answer (score 0):

Add .py files to a `.gitignore` file in the root directory (i.e. the same as `dbt_project.yml`. For instance:

**.gitignore**

```
**.py
```

When dbt executes it will still copy over the Python models. See additional comments on this topic [here](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/6061#issuecomment-1277852443).

Comment: but then I do not commit my python files to the git repo? This is not a solution

Comment: dbt builds a fresh instance (probably Docker) and copies the files. See a reference to the originally proposed solution here: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/6061#issuecomment-1277852443.

Comment: Also, make sure the name of the model function is specifically `model()`. This may be obvious, but it was an error I made previously.

Comment: Note that the adjustment above solved the issue for me.